# How can I use remote sharing (shooting on laptop) on Canon SX150 IS?

Tags: canon, digital, compact-cameras

I want to use remote shooting on canon sx 150 IS to capture a lecture through my camera but view it on my laptop screen connected via USB.What is the best way to do it?Can I use Zoombrowser EX with this camera model?How can I control this specific canon model through my laptop for video recording?

Thanks a lot for any help!!

[I hope I will not here that this facility is unsupported on this camera:-)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that the Canon PowerShot SX150 IS does not support remote capture. I've been looking for a way to do this myself and have not had any luck getting it to work.

> After the release of the G10 at the end of 2008 Canon stopped
>   including the ability to control PowerShot cameras from a PC and none
>   of their current models support this.
>
> http://www.breezesys.com/PSRemote/features.htm

Even more advanced software like [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) can't capture this model over USB even though the software does detect the camera once plugged in.